# Virtual Machine IP address type changed from static to dynamic

Tags: virtualization, ip, virtual-machines, scvmm

I am testing VMM in a lab environment, I have one VM host machine with one physical network adapter that has been allocated an IP address in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet on a router.

I have create logical management network and a virtual management network (direct access, no virtualization), they are included on a logical switch which is bound to the physical adapter on the host machine. The logical network has an IP Pool which has the subnet 192.168.5.0/24, additionally my host machine has an virtual adapter with a static IP address of 192.168.5.1 this is so that the host machine can see the VM's attached to the management network.

When I deploy a VM to the host with an vNIC attached to the virtual management network something very strange happens, or what I think is strange. Initially everything appears to work correctly, a vNIC is added to the VM:

[image: During the deploy a vNIC is added]

and an IP address from the correct pool is allocated to the vNIC

[image: Correct IP address allocation]

At this point all is well, everything is happening as I expect, however after the VM has warmed up, joined the domain, rebooted, etc. the following event appears:

[image: The strange event]

where the vNIC's address type is set to be dynamic, the allocated IP address is deallocated and it gets an IP address from the routers subnet 192.168.1.0/24.

I am *assuming* that this is because the adapter reaches out and discovers that there is a DHCP server through the hosts adapter and requests an address from the router. Although I would have thought it being set to static would have prevented that.

Is this expected behaviour?
What can I do to prevent this from happening?